# xPath expression for nested nodes

Tags: xpath, htmlcleaner

I'm trying to come up with a complex xPath expression but I can't figure out how to do that. Imagine you have some HTML like this:

```
<span>
    something1
    <br>
    something2
    <br>
    something3
</span>
```

Imagine that sometimes the second `<br>` and the subsequent "something3" are not present. I would like to create an xPath expression that takes all the span nodes and its content up to the first `<br>` so that I end up parsing just "something1". I don't know if this is possible, if not does anyone know a way to get that after having parsed all the `<span>` nodes?

I have to say that I'm using HtmlParser, which is a Java library which parses HTML and supports xPath expressions.

Thanks,

Masiar

Comment: So from the above example you want xpath to return **<span> something1<br></span>** ?

Comment: Yep, actually <span>something1</span> would be best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your description of the problem, but it sounds something like

```
//span/br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()
```

Comment: As are we all confused my friend :)

Comment: That sounds more or less what I am searching for. Thanks a lot, and sorry for the confused description :).